# CSS Images in Email With Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, html-email

I'm trying to send out an email with Rails 3 and Action Mailer. The email goes out fine, but I want it to be HTML formatted with some basic styling which includes background images. I understand that the images might get blocked until the user allows them to be shown, but I still think it would be best to link to the images on my web server.

The email template called registration_confirmation.html.erb starts out like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background: url(/images/mainbg_repeat.jpg) top repeat-x #cfcfcf;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #565656;
}
```

What is the best way to get the url link for the background image to have the full host included so that the background will show up in the email?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In response to my other answer, @Kevin wrote:

> Thanks for the answer, I did think of doing something like that but I
>   don't think it's possible with the way I have it setup. The mailer
>   call is happening in a after_create call in a model rather than in a
>   controller so I don't think I have access to the request object as you
>   mentioned (or am I mistaken). I do have this in my mailer initializer:
>   ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = "localhost:3000" Can I
>   somehow use that hos parameter in my mailer to make it work?

The answer is yes. All rails url-construction helpers should use these defualt_url_options. In addition to setting the `:host`, you should also force it to use absolute urls by settings this option:

```
ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:only_path] = false
```

Also, set the asset host like this:

```
config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'http://localhost:3000'
```

Then just use the `image_path` helper instead of hand-writing the url, like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background: url(<%= image_path('mainbg_repeat.jpg') %>) top repeat-x #cfcfcf;
}
</style>
```

*NOTE: Setting default_url_options directly like that is deprecated. Here's the new way to do it:*

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
    :host => 'localhost:3000',
    :only_path => false
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional answer, I've tried configuring things both the depricated and the new way and still can't get the full path with the host, I'll do some more research and see what I can find though. One other thing, when I use the image_tag as suggested, my email code comes like this: `background: url(<img alt="Mainbg_repeat" src="/images/mainbg_repeat.jpg" />) top repeat-x #cfcfcf;` Is image_tag the right helper to use? I don't want to have <img></img> in my css I don't think?

Comment: @Kevin, `image_tag` was a typo on my part. Meant to write `image_path`. Fixed that.

Comment: @Kevin, try explicitly setting `:only_path => false` in the image_path and see what happens. `image_path('mainbg_repeat.jpg', :only_path => false)`

Comment: It didn't like that either, `wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)` and image_path still doesn't give me the full path for some reason. I'll just pass the host in as a constant or something unless anyone has any other ideas. Thanks for all of your help with this though!

Comment: I have one more idea. Try: `config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'http://localhost:3000'` in your environment. Then use image_path as normal. Not sure if this will work, but it might. I updated my answer to show that.

Answer (score 2):

Pass your request host as a parameter to the mailer method, and then pass it from the method to the view. So, for example, your mailer method might look like this (example lifted from rails docs and modified here):

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "notifications@example.com"

  def registration_confirmation(user, host)
    @user = user
    @host = host
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Welcome to My Awesome Site")
  end
end
```

You would call it like this:

```
def some_action
    UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user, request.host).deliver
end
```

Then in your view, you would just use the @host:

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background: url(http://<%= @host %>/images/mainbg_repeat.jpg) top repeat-x #cfcfcf;
}
</style>
```

This is all assuming the image server is the same as the server running the request. If the image server is hosted elsewhere, you have to output a constant here. You could put something like this in lib/settings.rb:

```
module Settings
  IMAGE_HOST = 'superawesome.images.com'
end
```

Then in your view, you'd just output the constant there, like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background: url(http://<%= Settings::IMAGE_HOST %>/images/mainbg_repeat.jpg) top repeat-x #cfcfcf;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did think of doing something like that but I don't think it's possible with the way I have it setup. The mailer call is happening in a after_create call in a model rather than in a controller so I don't think I have access to the request object as you mentioned (or am I mistaken).
I do have this in my mailer initializer:
      `ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = "localhost:3000"`
Can I somehow use that hos parameter in my mailer to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about performance, the [roadie gem](https://github.com/Mange/roadie) can handle urls in the stylesheets for you.