# Adding images to devise Mailer templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Im trying to call `image_tag "image.jpg"` from devise Mailer template but since its an email sent, the path to the image would appear as broken in the email. (for not including the absolute url).

What's the best idea to solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Images in Email With Rails 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520936/css-images-in-email-with-rails-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the :host attribute for your mailer, same way you would approach building links

to do it globally you can do it inside your environment configuration as

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "example.com" }
```

take a look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html

for more info

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 4 the simplest way is to add the following to:

1. config/environments/development.rb

   config.action_mailer.asset_host = "http://localhost:3000"
2. config/environments/production.rb

   config.action_mailer.asset_host = "http://yourdomain.com"

Since emails are not pages hosted on your web server and are only relayed by your application to an smtp or other mailing server, this basically tells rails server where you're hosting mail assets. And in most cases you want to serve your mail assets from rails and specifically from the same assets path rails uses.

Doing this you can access your images simply by using image_tag.