# HTML email not showing full background image height

Tags: html, css

Only the top portion of the image is showing in an HTML email. I'm sending this using ActionMailer in Rails 3. How do I get the full length of the image to show?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  </head>
  <body>
        <table style="background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100% 100%;" width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20" background="https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/image.png">
                <tr><td></td></tr>
        </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any thoughts on this would be great. I just want to get the full contents of image.png to show up in an e-mail.

Comment: check this, might help you out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520936/css-images-in-email-with-rails-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the height of the table equal to the height of the image.  Just to let you know though, not all email clients support background images.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your html and body tags `style="height: 100%"`

or

Set the html tag to the height of your image `style="height: 550px"` and body tag to `style="height: 100%"`

[Fiddle example 100% tags](http://jsfiddle.net/FJsSj/) [Fiddle example with fixed height html tag](http://jsfiddle.net/FJsSj/1/)

Comment: You could also define with height of the html and body tags to the height of your image.