# rails email not displaying images from css

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, html-email

I don't really know how to approach this. I need to send some emails, with some design.

In my email.html.haml i have

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 

:css
  #backgroundTable {
    border-left: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    / background: #FFFFFF url("\#{root_path + asset_path('page-bg.gif')}"); 
    background-image: url('../assets/page-bg.gif')
  }
...
```

I tryied both versions, but none seem to work. Chrome's developer console doesn't report any errors, like it does when i miss something in the image name or similar.

I have multiple images from css and html img tags, but the ones from css work.

Thanks

Comment: maybe this could help you understand more??? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918414/what-is-the-right-way-to-embed-image-into-email-using-rails

Comment: You should know that not every HTML tags works probably in email's template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS for HTML emails must be inline, and many email clients cannot display all CSS entities.

MailChimp has a tool to help bring your CSS inline - http://beaker.mailchimp.com/inline-css

And Campaign Monitor has this great list of CSS elements and where they are supported - http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/