# Why do image tags work in regular views but not mailer views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4, html-email, actionmailer

Why does the below code show images on regular Rails views (webpages) but not show the images when used in mailer views (i.e. the emails I send from the app)? The images are located in /app/assets/images.

```
<%= image_tag "hr1.png" %>
<%= image_tag "pic_mountain.jpg" %>
<%= link_to image_tag("hr1.png", alt: "Sample alt text"), 'http://google.com' %>
```

As a follow up, is this the best way to include images in html emails being sent to users? Should I somehow store the images at www.url.com/images/sample_pic.jpg? If so, how do you do this? I'm using mailer classes I created that inherit from ActionMailer. Also, this is Rails 4.1.6. Thanks!

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918414/what-is-the-right-way-to-embed-image-into-email-using-rails

Answer (score 1):

The ERB you posted generates html of the form

```
<img src="/assets/hr1.png" />
```

(Iglorying asset digests for brevity), ie it contains only the path to the image and the browser uses the host and protocol the containing page was loaded from.

In an email this doesn't work because there is no such host. You can either include the host in the url or add the images as inline attachments.

The most basic way for the first is to do something along the lines of

```
image_tag(image_url("foo", host: "example.com"))
```

You can also set `default_url_options`  on your mailer so that you don't have to do this over and over again.

For inline attachments you first add the image as an attachment (in your mailer)

```
attachments.inline['foo.png'] = File.read(Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "images", "foo.png")
```

And then in your view you use it like so:

```
<%= image_tag attachments['foo.png'].url -%>
```

Note that this turns your email into a multipart email, so you shouldn't try and force the content type to text/html

Comment: Specifying the host didn't seem to work; however, the second suggestion with attachments.inline did work after I removed the content_type: text/html option from my call to the mail method. This was the main problem. Also, I specified the file path like this instead attachments.inline['pic_mountain.jpg'] = File.read("app/assets/images/pic_mountain.jpg")

Comment: Ah, yes, made a mistake on the url version