# Ruby on Rails: Why doesn't my image appear inline in the email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, email, ruby-on-rails-4

Within my Ruby on Rails application I am trying to embed a logo in an email to be displayed inline, but for some reason it does not appear (please see the below image). I have tried to follow the answers on this Stack Overflow question [What is the right way to embed image into email using Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918414/what-is-the-right-way-to-embed-image-into-email-using-rails) but cannot get it to work.

My mailer is as follows:

```
class UserEmails < ApplicationMailer
  def send_email(email, unsubscribe)
    @url  = 'http://localhost:3000/users/login'
    @email = email
    @unsubscribe = unsubscribe
    attachments.inline['logo.jpg'] = File.read('app/assets/images/logo.jpg')
    mail(from: "#{@email.from_name} <#{@email.account.email}>", to: @email.to, cc: @email.cc, bcc: @email.bcc, subject: @email.subject)
  end
end
```

And my email view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= @email.subject %></h1>
    <p>

    <p>
        To
      <%= image_tag attachments['logo.jpg'].url %>
      <%= link_to "Unsubscribe", settings_unsubscribe_url(id: @unsubscribe) %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is anyone able to tell me why this isn't working?

[image: image not displaying]

Comment: Can you upload your generated mail? export it as an eml file

Comment: Try `File.join(Rails.root, 'app/assets/images/logo.jpg')` to see if adding the root path fixes it.

Comment: @kobaltz thanks for your idea but that still didn't work, the result was the same