# The method `add_template_helper` does not seem to work in Rails 6.1

Tags: actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-6.1

After updating my project to Rails 6.1 I get this error:

```
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `add_template_helper' for ApplicationMailer:Class
```

In the documentation does not seem to be deprecated.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

So, apparently, this method was deleted without deprecation warning in this commit:

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/cb3b37b37975ceb1d38bec9f02305ff5c14ba8e9

So, the fix for this issue is to replace:

```rb
class MyMailer < ApplicationMailer
  add_template_helper MyHelper
```

With:

```rb
class MyMailer < ApplicationMailer
  helper MyHelper
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I had this exact same issue on the same day. This worked for me - thanks!

Comment: It is not working for me: undefined method `format_currency' for #<ActionView::Base:0x00000000092f90>

Comment: Note, you can also do `helper :my` and it will automatically include `MyHelper` (notice that you don't include `_helper` suffix when doing it this way).